# What's the difference between contravariance and inheritance in Java?

Tags: java, list, inheritance, contravariance

I have a parent class A, and its child class B. What is the difference between these two snippets :

```java
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ArrayList<? super A> e = new ArrayList<>();
        B thing = new B();
        e.add(thing);
        System.out.println(e.get(0));
    }
```

```java
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ArrayList<A> e = new ArrayList<>();
        B thing = new B();
        e.add(thing);
        System.out.println(e.get(0));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `ArrayList<? super A>` and `ArrayList<A>` is that the former can be assigned an object of `ArrayList<T>` where `T` is a superclass of `A` or `A` itself.

In concrete terms, this is valid:

```
ArrayList<? super A> listOfSuperA = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

This is not:

```
ArrayList<A> listOfA = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

This means that you can get values of different types out of `listOfA` and `listOfSuperA`:

```
A a = listOfA.get(0); // valid
Object o = listOfA.get(0); // valid, because A can be converted to Object.
A a2 = listOfSuperA.get(0); // invalid, because listOfSuperA could contain Objects, which are not convertible to A
Object o2 = listOfSuperA.get(0); // valid, because whatever is in listOfSuperA, it can be converted to Object
```

[This might be useful if you want to learn more about where to use `? super T`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)